# Math.random in a while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone help me?  I would like to make a simple code where dom generates a random number from 0-14 and adds it to the ran array and it will only stop once all numbers from 0-14 are inside the array.

```
function random () {
let ran = []
let dom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)
while (a != a.length(15)) {
   a.push(b)
   return a
 }
}

console.log(random)
```

Comment: You will be better off with a different approach: generate an array with consecutive numbers from 0 to 14 and shuffle it (google for Fisher-Yates or Durstenfeld).

Comment: You need to generate a new number inside the loop. You must *not* `return` inside the loop, since that ends it. You'll probably want to test whether the number is already in the array, not the array's length? Finally, this may be a lot easier by simply *shuffling* an array containing numbers from 0-14…?!

Comment: I might have overstepped by closing this as a duplicate of shuffling an array, but in all respects, that's the better solution. Just generating random values until you happen to find the missing piece is wildly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Logic.

- `random` function keeps on pushing random mnumbers from 0-14 to the `ran` array
- `checkAllNumberpresent` creates a number array from 0 - 14 using `Array.from(Array(15).keys())`
- This function accept the input array and check whther any numbers from the input array is missing in the `numberArray`
- If all are present, the function returns `false` and this stops the while loop execution.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function checkAllNumberpresent(arr) {
  const numberArray = Array.from(Array(15).keys());
  const missingNodes = numberArray.filter(item => arr.indexOf(item) === -1);
  return missingNodes.length == 0;
}
function random() {
  const ran = [];
  while (!checkAllNumberpresent(ran)) {
    let dom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
    ran.push(dom)
  }
  return ran
}

console.log(random())
```